# Invalid free() on structure

Tags: c, valgrind, free

I am extracting information from files and plugging them into a structure. However, I have difficulty freeing this structure in C. The structure is this:

```
typedef struct codelist{
    char *content;
    struct codelist *next;
}CodeList;

typedef struct comm{
    CodeList *compile;
    CodeList *test;
} Commands;
```

Here I read in the file info and malloc both CodeList and Commands structure

```
/*opens compile_cmds and test_cmds and puts their contents into a Command. 
Exits with 0 if error is found*/
Commands read_commands(const char *compile_cmds, const char *test_cmds){
    int status = 1;
    FILE *f1, *f2;

    if(compile_cmds == NULL || test_cmds == NULL)
        status = 0;
    f1 = fopen(test_cmds, "r");
    f2 = fopen(compile_cmds, "r");

    /*checks if compile_cmds and test_cmds are openable files*/
    if(f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL){
        status = 0;
    }
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);


    /*create dummy headers for compile and test lists*/
    if(status != 0){
        Commands *ans = malloc(sizeof(Commands));
        if(ans != NULL){

            ans->compile = helpread(compile_cmds);
            ans->test = helpread(test_cmds);
            return *ans;
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}

/*takes info out of filename and puts it into a linked list of content
return content*/
CodeList* helpread(const char *filename){
   char curr[256];
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    CodeList *code = malloc(sizeof(CodeList));
    if(code !=NULL && f != NULL){
        code->content = NULL;

        while(fgets(curr, 256, f)){
            CodeList *new = malloc(sizeof(CodeList));
            if(new == NULL)
                break;
            new->content = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(curr)+1));
            if(new->content == NULL)
                break;
            strcpy(new->content, curr);
            new->next = NULL;
            code->next = new;
            code = new;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return code;
}
```

And after I am done with them, I clear these structs so that memory used should be 0.
The read commands work well, what doesn't are the clear commands. While I am able to free the secondary structure, freeing the actual Commands structure gives me an invalid free() in valgrind. Can someone help me out with this?

```
/*clears CodeList
returns number of elements that were in CodeList*/
int helpclear(CodeList *code){
    int ans = 0;
    CodeList *prev;

    while(code !=NULL){
        prev = code;
        code = code->next;
        free(prev->content);
        free(prev);
        ans++;
   }
   return ans;
}


void clear_commands(Commands *commands){
    printf("enter clear_commands\n");
    if(commands !=NULL){
        helpclear(commands->test);
        helpclear(commands->compile);
        free(commands);
    }
    printf("done freeing test and compile\n");

   printf("end clear_commands\n");
}
```

Also, this is the result from valgrind:

```
==17133== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==17133==    at 0x4C27430: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==17133==    by 0x400E50: ??? (in       /afs/glue.umd.edu/class/fall2015/cmsc/216/0101/student-cmsc216-0403/chan2017/project6/public03.x)
==17133==    by 0x400B8F: ??? (in   /afs/glue.umd.edu/class/fall2015/cmsc/216/0101/student-cmsc216-0403/chan2017/project6/public03.x)
==17133==    by 0x4E4DD5C: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==17133==  Address 0x7ff000570 is on thread 1's stack
==17133==

Your code has a memory leak; memory still in use is 304 bytes.
==17133==
==17133== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17133==     in use at exit: 257 bytes in 13 blocks
==17133==   total heap usage: 20 allocs, 8 frees, 2,561 bytes allocated
==17133==
==17133== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17133==    definitely lost: 138 bytes in 5 blocks
==17133==    indirectly lost: 119 bytes in 8 blocks
==17133==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17133==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17133==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17133== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==17133==
==17133== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17133== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: " freeing the actual Commands structure gives me an invalid free() in valgrind". The valgrind output shows memory leaks. But there is no "invalid free" error shown. So is it just the memory leak you are asking about or are you seeing "invalid free" somewhere?

Comment: I added the errors from valgrind about the invalid free... whoops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `read_commands` the `malloc` buffer is not being returned. A copy of the structure (by value) is being returned instead.

```
Commands *ans = malloc(sizeof(Commands));
if(ans != NULL){
    ....
    return *ans;
}
```

You haven't shown how `read_commands` is being called. But no matter how it is called, the buffer that `ans` points to is lost and cannot be freed. So I assume you are somehow freeing what you think is a dynamically allocated `Commands` structure when in fact it is not so.

The `read_commands` function should be declared to return `Commands *` and not `Commands` and then it should return `ans` not `*ans`.

For more certainty, please show how `read_commands` is being called.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify why it must be Commands * and not Commands?

Comment: I got it! This was it

Answer (score 0):

For the first element in a list as allocated here

```
CodeList* helpread(const char *filename){
  char curr[256];
  FILE *f;
  CodeList *code = malloc(sizeof(CodeList));
```

... the code misses to initialise the member `content`, so its pointing nowhere. The code should initialise it to `NULL`.

---

Also the code never does any error checking on the result of `malloc()` and `fopen()`.

---

Also^2 the code does not handle the case of empty files or read errors in a safe manner.

Comment: @Justin: But the code tries to free it along with its not existing content?

Comment: I didn't init the first element's content because I am going with using empty headers. I will add the cases of empty files and errors in malloc and fopen though

Comment: Is that really necessary though? My understanding is that free can work with anything that is malloc'd